# Wheel dependencies - No matching distribution found

Tags: python, pip, python-wheel

I wanted to distribute my software via PyPi. My `pyproject.toml` configuration file looks like this:

```
[build-system]
requires = ["hatchling"]
build-backend = "hatchling.build"

[project]
name = "saoovqe"
version = "0.1.6"
authors = [
...
]
description = "MyPackage"
readme = "README.md"
requires-python = ">=3.10"
classifiers = [
    "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
    "License :: OSI Approved :: GNU General Public License v3 (GPLv3)",
    "Operating System :: POSIX :: Linux",
]
dependencies=[
    "qiskit>=0.43.0",
    "qiskit-nature>=0.6.2",
    "numpy>=1.22.0,<1.24.0",
    "deprecated>=1.2.14",
    "mendeleev>=0.13.1",
    "scipy>=1.10.1",
    "sympy>=1.11.1",
    "setuptools>=67.8.0",
    "lxml>=4.9.2",
    "nlopt",
    "ipython",
    "jupyter",
    "pygments",
    "scikit-learn>=1.2.2",
    "icecream>=2.1.3",
    "pytest>=7.3.1"
]
```

Creating of Wheel and subsequent upload are OK. The problem is, when I try to install the package from PyPi like this

```
 pip install -i https://test.pypi.org/simple/ saoovqe==0.1.6
```

I'm getting the following error

```
Looking in indexes: https://test.pypi.org/simple/
Collecting saoovqe==0.1.6
  Obtaining dependency information for saoovqe==0.1.6 from https://test-files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c2/6e/4061ed360f3e942caffd9056c4cbda4908fa85718a99d6323a69ada828d7/saoovqe-0.1.6-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
  Downloading https://test-files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c2/6e/4061ed360f3e942caffd9056c4cbda4908fa85718a99d6323a69ada828d7/saoovqe-0.1.6-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.7 kB)
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of saoovqe to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement deprecated>=1.2.14 (from saoovqe) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for deprecated>=1.2.14
```

As can be seen [here](https://pypi.org/project/Deprecated/), the package `Deprecated` really is available at the version 1.2.14. So, what is wrong with my configuration? I'd like to be able to specify the dependencies in a way, that they'll get downloaded automatically, if the package is installed.

Comment: What was the exact command? You limited `pip` to use only TestPyPI. If the command was `pip install -i https://test.pypi.org/simple` add the main URL: `pip install --index-url https://test.pypi.org/simple --extra-index-url https://pypi.org/simple` If you set the test URL in `pip.conf` — remove it from the config.

Comment: @phd Cool, it works! Could you, please, write your answer with `extra-index-url` and explain it in a little more detail, so that I could accept it?